# drag & drop w/ reordering - reordering 2 side-by-side elements at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have had no luck figuring out how to do this.  I was originally using jQuery UI sortable, but I am not sure it will work with this workflow:

I have a table with multiple columns.  I want to be able to drag an element in column A AND the element next to it in column B at once and drop them into a different position.  After the drop, the element from column A & B will still be side-by-side but not at their original Y coordinate.  The key is dragging them at once & allowing other elements that cross their paths to "move out of the way".

I was able to achieve this with 1 element using jquery UI sortable, but am not sure how to make this work with two side-by-side elements.  Any suggestions any help is more than welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use row's as handlers?

By your description A & B are always 1 element being dragged.

Comment: well, there is one element to move in each row, so a total of 2 elements.  Perhaps I am not understanding correctly?

Comment: @user486979 what I meant is why not to attach the handler to the row instead of the individual elements?